# SageMaker Endpoint: ServiceUnavailable 503 when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I've deployed a model as SageMaker Endpoint, it worked fine for some time but now when invoking the model through boto3

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName="my-sagemaker-endpoint",
        ContentType="text/csv",
        Body=payload,
)
```

I got the following error

```
ServiceUnavailable: An error occurred (ServiceUnavailable) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation (reached max retries: 4): A transient exception occurred while retrieving variant instances. Please try again later.
```

Researching about this error in [SageMaker Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html) it states the following

> The request has failed due to a temporary failure of the server.

I've also checked the Instance Metrics in CW and there's nothing unusual.

I'm not sure why this error is happening, any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: 1\ Are you able to re-deploy to a new endpoint, does the issue still occur?
2\ Are there any errors in the CW logs?

Comment: Hi @MarcK , I had to redeploy the model to a new endpoint, notice that this happened with a single instance endpoint, apparently the model artifact got deleted by error, would provide an answer shortly explaining what I think could happened.

Answer (score 0):

> TL; DR The error originates because the Instance is unable to retrieve the SageMaker Model artifact from s3.

### Explanation

SageMaker Endpoints implement a `/ping` route which check if model artifact is able to load within the Instance. The model artifacts is first retrieved from s3 and then loaded into the instance. If model is not available on s3 it shows the following error (image below)
[image]

As the model artifact can't be retrieved from s3 because it was accidentally deleted, it can't be loaded which raises the error `No such file or directory` when calling the `/ping` route to check if the endpoint is healthy (see image below)

[image]

This in turn makes the Load Balancer to assume the instance has some problem, blocking you access to it, so when you try to invoke the endpoint you get a `503: Service Unavailable Error`

[image]

### Solution

I worked this out only by redeploying to a new endpoint but this time considering the following:

- At least `num_instances=2` to guarantee each instance is at a different AZ, and the LB communicates with at least a healthy instance.
- Ensure only specific roles have `s3:PutObject` permission on the s3 model artifacts route `models/model-name/version`